# Inbox-like Search

Tags: android, searchview, google-inbox

I have a searchview I'm using, specifically, [PersistentSearch](https://github.com/Quinny898/PersistentSearch). Regardless of this library, I'm trying to figure out what Inbox does in terms of how it shows the search results.

- What needs to happen so that it opens a view where the results can be polled? (I want to say they are displaying a fragment over the `MainActivity`, but I'm not sure)
- How do you display the fragment or activity over another activity like they do?

There seems to be very little written on how to accomplish like this.

Thanks in advance. (I'm not expecting code answers--I really just need to know what needs to be done, as I can't find good sources on how to do something like Inbox is doing.